# Execute commands with speech asynchronously

Tags: c#, speech-recognition

We have our thesis revision and one panelist said that to make our speech recognition system better is to add a way to process a command.

For example if i give a default command

```
case "What time is it?":
WVASRS.Speak("time");
break;
```

I want the system to be able to tell the user that the COMMAND is still processing before the user can give another command. Something like:

```
//I will give a command while the the other command is processing
case "What day is it":
WVASRS.Speak("day");
break;

WVASRS.Speak("Another command is still processing. Please Wait for a few seconds before you can give another command.");
```

Well, if found something on MSDN but it just does nothing. here is the snippet:

```
    // Assign input to the recognizer and start asynchronous
    // recognition.
    recognizer.SetInputToDefaultAudioDevice();

    completed = false;
    Console.WriteLine("Starting asynchronous recognition...");
    recognizer.RecognizeAsync(RecognizeMode.Multiple);

    // Wait 30 seconds, and then cancel asynchronous recognition.
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
    recognizer.RecognizeAsyncCancel();

    // Wait for the operation to complete.
    while (!completed)
    {
      Thread.Sleep(333);
    }
    Console.WriteLine("Done.");
```

Comment: By doing nothing, perhaps the program runs and terminates before the speechRecognizer completes the work. If you could add more details on what happened, that would be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The code from MSDN is more or less correct, you just miss the handler of recognized command, see the complete example [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.speech.recognition.speechrecognizer.speechhypothesized(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
 recognizer.SpeechRecognized +=
          new EventHandler<SpeechRecognizedEventArgs>(recognizer_SpeechRecognized);
```

and later

```
// Handle the SpeechRecognized event.
static void recognizer_SpeechRecognized(object sender, SpeechRecognizedEventArgs e)
{

  if (actionRunning) {
      speak("Busy");
  }
  if (e.Result.Text.Equals("what is the time")) {
      actionRunning = true;
      startAction() 
  }
  Console.WriteLine("Speech recognized: " + e.Result.Text);
}
```